# Floating Point in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm having some strange results when trying to match some values in a pandas dataframe - Essentially, I have the following unique values

```
array([18.        , 18.04000092, 18.07999992, 18.12000084, 18.15999985,
       18.20000076, 18.23999977, 18.28000069, 18.31999969, 18.36000061,
       18.39999962])
```

But when I try to match one of those values to the dataframe, I'm getting nothing

Example

```
t1 = R[R.lat == 18.04000092]


time    speed_x Speed_Estimated direction_x Direction_Estimated lat lon time
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that when I extract only that column, I can see pandas round it up the number

```
R['lat']

1573052    18.0
1573053    18.0
1573054    18.0
1573055    18.0
1573056    18.0
           ... 
1578740    18.4
1578741    18.4
1578742    18.4
1578743    18.4
1578744    18.4
Name: lat, Length: 2106, dtype: float64
```

So basically pandas internally is rounding up the numbers, so my question is what's the best approach?, should I change the values so pandas doesn't round up?, but then why when I extract the unique values, pandas is showing the numbers in a different format?

Comment: I think you'll find the issue is the numbers are truncated when printed to screen, rather than being rounded by pandas.

Comment: Thanks, so why is it failing to compare both numbers?

Comment: possibly it's still being truncated.  This might be useful for you https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making both columns exactly the same datatype, after that, I was able to compare the numbers easily.

```
d[d.select_dtypes(np.float64).columns] = d.select_dtypes(np.float64).astype(np.float32)
```

I never come across this issue before, but makes sense as the float resolution of each number is different, so the number itself is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 8)
R = pd.DataFrame(np.array([18.        , 18.04000092, 18.07999992, 18.12000084, 18.15999985,
       18.20000076, 18.23999977, 18.28000069, 18.31999969, 18.36000061,
       18.39999962]))
R.columns = ['lat']
R
```

Comment: Thanks, but those are the unique values, it does work  R[R.lat == 18.04000092] - that code matches correctly the values, but that is one column corresponding to the unique values, my dataframe is 2016 row repeating those unique values