# How i can filter a dataframe with another dataframe column, both have different index and few value in second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame `file` and a second data frame `time`.
and file data frames has `30398 rows` data and time data frames has `70 rows` data.

file =

[image]

time =

[image]

And now I want to filter `file.Time == time`
but it's giving me error -

```
Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

[image]

My code -

```
def FilteringData():
    con_a, con_b, con_c = [], [], []
    min_expiry = file.EXPIRY.min()
    for i in time:
        print(i, "\n")
        condition_a = file[(file.EXPIRY == min_expiry) &
                          (file.OPTION_TYPE == op) &
                          (file.STRIKE_PRICE == str(main_strike)) &
                          (file.TIME == i)]
        condition_b = file[(file.EXPIRY == min_expiry) &
                          (file.OPTION_TYPE == op) &
                          (file.STRIKE_PRICE == str(add_strike)) &
                          (file.TIME == i)]
        condition_c = file[(file.EXPIRY == min_expiry) &
                          (file.OPTION_TYPE == op) &
                          (file.STRIKE_PRICE == str(sub_strike)) &
                          (file.TIME == i)]
        con_a.append(condition_a)
        con_b.append(condition_b)
        con_c.append(condition_c)
    return con_a, con_b, con_c   
con_a, con_b, con_c = FilteringData()
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want rows of "file" where its "Time" is in the entries of "time" df?

Comment: Yes. i want to check file.Time == time is true then print File.TIme values.

Comment: One of the likely reasons for the error is that your time series time is not the same data type as your column Time on your file.. First check the data type for both columns using this command - file.dtypes and time.dtypes - make sure both of the columns are exactly the same time format, if the columns data type is not the same, you will have to convert the format in one of the columns, only then you can do the comparison, please look at my solution to my own problem which is very similar to your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780022/floating-point-in-a-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the rows of file in which the value for the column TIME exists in the time series, then you can simply do a slicing operation.

`out = file[file['TIME'].isin(time)]`

Another option is to do a `merge` so oniy records on both files are kept:

`Out = file.merge(time.to_frame(),left_on='TIME',right_on='TIME')`